# Understanding a Javascript Decrypter

Tags: javascript, loops, encryption

I'm looking at a codewars solution for decrypting a set of numbers.
For example,

012345 => 304152 => 135024

So the 012 would take on every other index starting from 1, and 345 would take on every other index starting from 0.  The solution is written as...

```
const decrypt = (s, n) => {
  if (!s) return s;
  const l = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let x = s.slice(0, l), y = s.slice(l);
    s = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < l + 1; j++) 
      s += (y[j] ? y[j] : '') + (x[j] ? x[j] : '');
  }
  return s;
}
```

From my understanding, the coder sliced the number into two halves, and the for loop runs through the digits in the first half and also the last digits in the second half.  I'm not sure why there needs to be a ternary operator there and what conditions it's looking for. I'd appreciate any help!

I tried doing the s+= y[j] + x[j] and thought it would decrypt.  I get the right answer, but there's an extra undefined statement at the end of the solution.

Comment: _“what conditions it's looking for”_ — [Truthiness](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#parameters). Since [`slice`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) returns a string, `y[j]` can only be falsy if it reports `undefined`, i.e. this is a test if the index `j` is in `y`. `Object.hasOwn(y, j)` is preferable.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!  That makes more sense; I'm going to mull over that